# Is it possible to add where clause in html.partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have html.partial in my html markup which is getting and displaying all the records from database. but i want to change it to selected records.. i mean i want to put where clause in html.partial.. is it possible to add where clause in partial and filter the records?
my html markup is like this

```
@Html.Partial("ListProductPartial", Model.Data.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id))
```

i am very much new to asp.net mvc. i am using pre defined code and want to understand the code. i hope you guys will help me to resolve this issue..

Comment: Your example looks valid as long as the data type matches the HtmlPartials model type. `Model.Data.Where(x=>x,Id > 20).OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).ToList()` I would recommend you call `.ToList();` on your model where/order by clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your model, this should work (keeping the OrderByDescending):

```
@Html.Partial("ListProductPartial", Model.Data.Where(o => o.Name == "FilterText").OrderByDescending(o => o.Id))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend this style but you can try this sample;

Partial View

```
@model List<WebApplication4.Models.WebModelData>

@{

    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.Raw(item.Value)
    }
}
```

Call to partial

```
@Html.Partial("PartialView", Model.Data.Where(o => o.Id > 5).ToList())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Controller:

 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Student> ob = new List<Student>()
            {
                new Student{ id=1, Name="x"},
                new Student{ id=2, Name="y"},
            };
            return View(ob);
        }

Index:

@model List<WebApplication15.Controllers.Student>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@Html.Partial("Name",Model.OrderByDescending(x=>x.id))
<h2>Index</h2>

Partial View:
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication15.Controllers.Student>

@foreach (var student in Model)
{
    <li>@student.id</li>
    <li>@student.Name</li>
}
```